# Writing “the class of 2014”  in a résumé?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, terminology

Is *“class of 2014”* correct?

Is *“class of ’14”* correct?

Assuming the reader is aware of the context, is simply using *“’14”* correct?

Comment: There ain't a lot of people what graduated in 1914 still looking for jobs.

Comment: Well, there are NO people who graduated in 2014 yet.

Comment: There are, however, people who *will* graduate in 2014, and they could be looking for jobs, whether in high school or college.

Comment: Like me! Future class of '14...Unless I get screwed over, which is entirely possible...

Comment: You should capitalize it in any event, as it is a proper noun: *the Class of 2023* and such.

Answer (score 4):

Does your college/university have a writing style guide? If you look at the different style guides of different universities, you'll find that each style guide has its own prescribed way of handling class years.

From [Middlebury](http://www.middlebury.edu/offices/news/communications/styleguide/classyears)

> Classes from previous centuries that 
>   duplicate numerals of classes in the 
>   present century should be written in 
>   full.
>
> John Smith, Class of 1906
>
> John Smith II ’60 (referring to 1960)
>
> John Smith III ’06 (referring to 2006)

From [Knox](http://www.knox.edu/offices-and-services/public-relations/style-guide.html#cy)

> Use an “s” without an apostrophe after 
>   the year to indicate spans of decades 
>   or centuries. Use an apostrophe before 
>   the year for class years or abbreviations
>   to indicate the “20” or “19” is omitted. 
>   See Class Year.
>
> Right: The College was formed in the 1830s.
>
> Right: Shannon will graduate with the Class of ’03.

From [University of Texas at Austin](http://www.utexas.edu/visualguidelines/dates.html)

> Use an “s” without an apostrophe after 
>   the year to indicate spans of decades 
>   or centuries. Use an apostrophe before 
>   the year for class years or abbreviations
>   to indicate the first two numbers of the 
>   year are omitted.
>
> Right: The university was formed in the 1880s.
>
> Right: She belonged to the Class of 1924.
>
> Right: Shannon will graduate with the Class of ’03.
>
> Wrong: The ‘60s were famous for hippies, flower power and the peace movement.
>
> Right: Marcia Gay Harden, B.A. ’80, spoke to 
>   the College of Fine Arts graduating class of 2001.

Answer (score 3):

*Class of 2014* seems more formal to me than *Class of ’14*.  That might make it the better option on a résumé.

Comment: I would use the full numeric for much the same reason that I would avoid any contraction in a document like a resume: it's too informal for my taste.

Answer (score 3):

The expression *class of—* is rarely used in resumes. One either explicitly states the graduation date, e.g. *[Expected] Date of Graduation: June 2014*, or indicates their years of attendance to date, e.g. *2010 – present/date: American College, USA*.

If you must use *class of—*, however, *class of 2014* is the way to go. *Class of '14* does not sound formal enough. For years below 2000, especially from the 50s up, it sounds better to drop the *19*. From 2000 and up, though, it's nicer to retain the *20*.